# Why doesn't the expectation of position for a plane wave obey kinematics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, plane-wave

Consider the plane wave: 
$$\Psi = Ne^{i(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r} - Et)/\hbar}$$
with *N* is the normalisation factor.

The expectation value of momentum for this wave is:
$$\begin{align}
\langle\vec{p}\rangle
&= \int_\text{all space} \Psi^{*} \hat{p} \Psi\ \mathrm{d}V \\
&= \int_\text{all space} Ne^{-i(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r} - Et)/\hbar} (-i\hbar \nabla) Ne^{i(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r} - Et)/\hbar}\ \mathrm{d}V \\
&= -i\hbar N^2\int_\text{all space} e^{-i(\vec{p}.\vec{r} - Et)/\hbar} (i\vec{p}/\hbar) e^{i(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r} - Et)/\hbar}\ \mathrm{d}V \\
&= (-i\hbar)(i\vec{p}/\hbar) N^2\int_\text{all space} e^{-i(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r} - Et)/\hbar}e^{i(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r} - Et)/\hbar}\ \mathrm{d}V \\
&= (-i\hbar)(i\vec{p}/\hbar) 1 \\
\langle\vec{p}\rangle &= \vec{p}
\end{align}$$

Everything seems to be OK by now. Lets now find the expectation value of position for this wave:
$$\begin{align}
\langle\vec{r}\rangle
&= \int_\text{all space} \Psi^{*} \hat{r} \Psi\ \mathrm{d}V \\
&= \int_\text{all space} Ne^{-i(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r} - Et)/\hbar} (\vec{r}) Ne^{i(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{r} - Et)/\hbar}\ \mathrm{d}V
\end{align}$$
By symmetry of the integration, $\langle\vec{r}\rangle = \vec{0} $.

We should have (from [Ehrenfest theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem)):
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}\langle\vec{r}\rangle}{\mathrm{d} t} = \frac{\langle\vec{p}\rangle}{m}$$
However this is not satisfied, because $ \frac{\mathrm{d} \langle\vec{r}\rangle}{\mathrm{d} t} = \frac{\delta \vec{0}}{\delta t} = \vec{0}$,
which is not, in general, equal to $\langle\vec{p}\rangle/m = \vec{p}/m$. So, what is wrong here?

Comment: What fails is that plane waves are not true vectors. In particular, your integral for $\bar{\vec{r}}$ is essentially undefined.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform that should be an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plane wave $\psi_p(x) = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}px}$ is *not* a quantum state for a free particle. The integral $\int_\mathbb{R} \psi_p(x)\psi^\ast_p(x)\mathrm{d}x$ does not converge, and it is in particular not $1$ as you use in your calculation of the expectation value of $p$. This means the expectation value of $p$ is *undefined*, or rather, that you shouldn't let $p$ act on this object in the first place - it is not inside the domain of definition of the momentum operator.

Although the plane wave is an *eigenfunction* of the differentiation operation, it is not an eigenstate of the momentum operator, since states are *by definition* square-integrable functions.

Comment: Also you might want to add, that the variance is infinite. And even if you approximate the state (via cutoff functions) to be finite, you can get any expectation value, but also the variance increases to infinity.